# What is the conventional method to filter pages in the Django-cms rest api?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-cms, django-filters

As far as I know, the django-cms rest api does not provide rest api filters.  I need to filter by the published page title so that ?t=XX will return the published version of that page.  I've written one, but I'd like to know if I'm using "title_set" appropriately in this case.

```
class PageViewSet(QuerysetMixin, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PageSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    site = get_current_site(self.request)
    t = self.request.query_params.get('t', None)
    queryset = Page.objects.filter(publisher_is_draft=False).all()
    if t is not None:
        # return the page with cms_title.title = t
        return queryset.filter(title_set__title__exact=t)
    else:
        # default to the home page
        return queryset.filter(title_set__title__exact='Home')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend), django-filters is so convenient~